# Calculate weight using normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I have to add a weight column in the titanic dataset to calculate adult passengers' weight using a normal distribution with std = 20 and mean = 70 kg. I have tried this code:

```
df['Weight'] = np.random.normal(20, 70, size=891)
df['Weight'].fillna(df['Weight'].iloc[0], inplace=True)
```

but I am concerned about two things:

1. It generates negative values, not just positive; how can this be considered normal weight value, is there anything that I can change in code to generate just positive values.
2. Since I am targeting the adults' age group, what about children. Some of them also have abnormal weight values, such as 7 kg for adults or 30 kg for a child; how can this be solved.
   I appreciate any help you can provide.

Edit:

This code worked for me

```
Weight = np.random.normal(80, 20, 718)
adults['Weight'] = Weight
```

Now I have to calculate probability for people weighted less than 70
and who is between 70 and 100.

I have tried the following code but it raise an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

adults = df[(df['Age'] >= 20) & (df['Age'] <= 70)]

Weight = np.random.normal(80, 20, 718)
adults['Weight'] = Weight

p1 = adults['Weight'] < 70
p2 = adults[(adults['Weight'] > 70) & (adults['Weight'] < 100)]

scipy.stats.norm.pdf(p1)
scipy.stats.norm.pdf(p2)
```

Comment: If you want a truly normal distribution with a mean of 70 and dev of 20 then you won't get those other two things. Once you start adding those other restrictions it won't be a normal distribution, so it's unclear what the problem requirement is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Range of a Normal distribution is not restricted. It spans all across real numbers. If you want to restrict it, you should do it manually or use other distributions.

   ```
   df['Weight'] = np.random.normal(20, 70, size=891)
   df.loc[df['Weight'] < min_value, 'Weight'] = min_value
   df.loc[df['Weight'] > max_value, 'Weight'] = max_value
   ```
2. Since weights of children and adults are not iid's you should sample it from different distributions

   ```
   # use different distributions
   df.loc[df['person_type'] == 'child', 'Weight'] = np.random.normal(x1, y1, size=children_size)
   df.loc[df['person_type'] == 'adult', 'Weight'] = np.random.normal(x2, y2, size=adult_size)
   ```

Comment: I tried this code but the random Weight values are the same for all ages. Can you help me with this. `adults = df[df['Age'] >= 20].reset_index(drop=True)

adults['Weight'] = np.random.normal(20, 70)

adults.loc[(adults['Age'] == 'adults') & (adults['Weight'] >= 40)]

adults['Weight'].fillna(adults['Weight'].iloc[0], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [truncated normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html), if you want to avoid negative values, for example, to get a vector of with mean 70 and sd 20, you can do:

```
myclip_a = 0
myclip_b = +np.Inf
my_mean = 70
my_std = 20

a, b = (myclip_a - my_mean) / my_std, (myclip_b - my_mean) / my_std
```

We set the seed, and you can see the truncated normal has all values above zero, but not the normal u have used:

```
np.random.seed(100)

x1 = truncnorm.rvs(a= a,b=b,size=50000,loc=70,scale=20)

np.sum(x1<0)
0

x2 = norm.rvs(loc=70,scale=20,size=50000)

np.sum(x2<0)
10
```

Not very sure how you are filling in the nas.. Will need the data frame to address that but I suspect its another question altogether.